# Code for finding path for max sum in matrix not working

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, matrix

This is my code:

```js
const foo = (matrix, n = matrix.length, m = matrix[0].length, x = 0, y = 0) => {
  if (x == m-1 && y == n-1) return matrix[x][y];
  if (x < m-1 && y < n-1) return matrix[x][y] + Math.max(foo(matrix, n, m, x+1, y), foo(matrix, n, m, x, y+1));
  if (x == m-1) return matrix[x][y] + foo(matrix, n, m, x, y+1);
  if (y == n-1) return matrix[x][y] + foo(matrix, n, m, x+1, y);
}

const matrix = [
  [ 4, 2, 9, 6 ],
  [ 7, 1, 12, 11 ],
  [ 10, 13, 3, 8 ]
];

console.log(foo(matrix));
```

I'm getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')** in the 4th line.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up `x` and `y`. `y` is the "vertical" direction, and you compare it correctly with `n` -- the number of rows in the matrix -- but then you use `y` as index in the **inner** array (as if it was an `x` coordinate). This is wrong. So swap `x` and `y` in all that indexing:

```js
const foo = (matrix, n = matrix.length, m = matrix[0].length, x = 0, y = 0) => {
  if (x == m - 1 && y == n - 1) return matrix[y][x];
  if (x < m - 1 && y < n - 1) return matrix[y][x] + Math.max(foo(matrix, n, m, x + 1, y), foo(matrix, n, m, x, y + 1));
  if (x == m - 1) return matrix[y][x] + foo(matrix, n, m, x, y + 1);
  if (y == n - 1) return matrix[y][x] + foo(matrix, n, m, x + 1, y);
}

const matrix = [
  [ 4, 2, 9, 6 ],
  [ 7, 1, 12, 11 ],
  [ 10, 13, 3, 8 ]
];

console.log(foo(matrix));
```

Not your question, but consider using memoization to reduce the time complexity of your algorithm.